# How to get Youtube live stream location?

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to get the location using JQuery or PHP of a live Youtube channel but it's not clear with the V3 API. Many examples out there are with the V2 API. I want that location to display the current live stream location using the Google Maps API.

I already tried the examples of the Youtube Data API with their API Explorer, but without luck because those examples are only about searching live channels on an specific location, not the other way around.

Thanks in advance for any help!

David

Comment: Consider using the [tag:youtube-livestreaming-api] tag for questions relating to YouTube's LiveStreaming API.

Answer (score 0):

In [Youtube V3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) there are 2 properties about geolocation:
- recordingDetails.location -> current live stream 
- fileDetails.recordingLocation  -> for video recorded

Try with that.